# How to print element with querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I have this list of elements:

```
<ul class="connected">
  <li class="name">Alex</li>
  <li class="name">Laura</li>
</ul>
```

How can I print the names? I've tried: `connected.querySelector(".name")` but prints the entire label: `<li class = "name">Alex</li>`.
I want to know how I can print only the names, 'Alex', for example.

Comment: _"The Document method `querySelector()` returns **the first [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)** within the document that matches the specified selector"_ - Check the properties of `Element` and you will find one that will fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the `innerText` property of the element. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

```js
const names = document.querySelectorAll('.name');
for (let name of names) {
  console.log(name.innerText);
}
```

```html
<ul class="connected">
  <li class="name">Alex</li>
  <li class="name">Laura</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use **textContent** or **innerHTML** in this case as all innerText, textContent and innerHTML have similar functionality.
But there are some slight differences among them:

- textContent property sets or returns the text content of the
  specified node, and all its descendants.
- innerText will not return the text of elements that are hidden with
  CSS but textContent will return.
- The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML)
  of an element. So use them according to the need.

```
const names = document.querySelectorAll('.name');
for (let name of names) {
  console.log(name.textContent);
}
for (let name of names) {
  console.log(name.innerHTML);
}
<ul class="connected">
  <li class="name">Alex</li>
  <li class="name">Laura</li>
</ul>
```

and one more point to remember:
**The textContent property is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, and the innerText property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier.**